# Make text start from bottom

Tags: css

I'll try to simplify my problem to make it easier to understand.

I want to be able to add lines of text (using javascript) to the document at the bottom of the page.
When a new line is pushed, it's added at the bottom, pushing all the previous lines up.

The document should be padded and when the content overflows the older lines (top ones) should be hidden or using scroll in which case it should be scrolled to the bottom.

I've been trying to accomplish this for a while now but I can't any elegant solutions.
Any ideas? css3 is more than welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: I think that your goal is chatting application!

Comment: Is this to be updated on the fly like a live feed? If not, surely this is a simple CSS position of element?

Comment: No, not a chat. And yes, it updates "on the fly".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an HTML element do this by default it is UL just include it inside an fixed height div with overflow and some focus on the last LI!

Comment: Ah yes, I tried this already which seemed like the best approach, but it did not work. Now after your answer I got back to it and all I did wrong was to add `max-height: 100%` to the ul.