# Start Content from bottom of container and push up

Tags: html, css

So what I'm trying to accomplish seems like easy CSS etc. Im changing a messaging system and what the conversations to start at the bottom sorta like Facebook or text message where it has one person on the left and the other on the right.

How do I get the divs to go up as new content is added via ajax? I saw this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353049/make-text-start-from-bottom) but didn't quite understand what he mean focus on the LI. An example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}
function newTxt(txt){return document.createTextNode(txt);}
function prependChild(parent, element)
{
    if (parent.childNodes)
        parent.insertBefore(element, parent.childNodes[0]);
    else
        parent.appendChild(element)
}


window.addEventListener('load', mInit, false);

function mInit()
{
    byId('btnAddNew').addEventListener('click', onAddBtnClicked, false);
}

function onAddBtnClicked()
{
    var txtInputElem = byId('newMsgTxtInput');
    var msgTxt = txtInputElem.value;

    var li = newEl('li');
    li.appendChild( newTxt( msgTxt ) );

    var ulTgt = byId('msgTarget');

    var existingLiItems = ulTgt.querySelectorAll('li');
    var numItemsExisting = existingLiItems.length;
    if (numItemsExisting%2 != 0)
        li.className = 'even';
    else
        li.className = 'odd';

    prependChild(ulTgt, li);
}

</script>
<style>
.controls
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 8px;
    border: solid 1px #555;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #777;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
#msgTarget
{
    width: 275px;
    border: solid 1px #555;
    margin: 8px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

/*
 Doesn't work 'properly' - since we add items at the top, rather than the bottom
 The first item added will be 'even', then the second item gets added and now it's the first child 'even'
 so, the item added first is now an 'odd' child. A better way may be to count the number of existing li
 items the ul contains, before assigning the new li elements a class of even or odd that will enable css
 styling.
#msgTarget li:nth-child(odd)
{   
    background-color: #CCC;
}
#msgTarget li:nth-child(even)
{   
    background-color: #5C5;
}
*/

.odd
{   
    background-color: #CCC;
}
.even
{   
    background-color: #5C5;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='dlg'>
        <div class='controls'>
            <input id='newMsgTxtInput'/><button id='btnAddNew'>Add message</button>
        </div>
        <ul id='msgTarget'></ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, I found a way to do it that I like ok.